# Confused about calling on methods containing 'try-catch' blocks

Tags: java, try-catch, calling-convention

If you write a non-main method which contains a try-catch block, and later, inside another method, you want to call on that method, what's the procedure? I can't figure it out.

My own case is the following:

For a simple Java 'maze game', I wrote a static void method called 'saveGame(String mazeGameSave) throws IO Exception'. This method contained a 'try' block in which I wrote all the code necessary to print the 'board' (as a 2-d array) to a new file, and then a short 'catch' block where I just printed out an error message (the same one you can see below).

Obviously, I then wanted to call on this method in another static void method set up for handling other methods, as specified by user input, and I did this exactly as you can see below, where the String "action" is the argument of the static void method containing this block.

```
if (action.charAt(0) == ('S' | 's') 
        && action.charAt(1) == ('a' | 'A') 
        && action.charAt(2) == ('v' | 'V') 
        && action.charAt(3) == ('e' | 'E') 
        && action.charAt(4) == ' ') {
    String [] parts = action.split(" ");
    String saveCommand = parts[0];
    String fileName = parts[1];
    try {
        saveGame(fileName); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Error: Could not save the current game configuration to \'%s\'. \n", fileName);
    }
}
```

Following my commenters' suggestions, here is the saveGame() code:

```
   public static void saveGame (String mazeGameSave) throws IOException {
   File save = new File(mazeGameSave);
     try {
      PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("mazeGameSave");
      output.printf(lives + " " + steps + " " + gold + " " + boardRows + "\n");
     for (int j = 0; j < boardRows; j ++) {
     for (int k = 0; k < columns; k ++) {
      output.print(board[j][k]);
      }
      output.print("\n");
      }
      output.close();
       output.printf("Successfully saved the current game configuration to \'%s\'.", mazeGameSave);
         }
       catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Error: Could not save the current game configuration to \'%s\'.", mazeGameSave);
       return;
        }}
```

So the key dumb aspect of this is that I have written out exactly the same 'catch' block in the performAction(action) method as I did in my original saveGame(...) method. And this doesn't work... So what do I do???

Comment: Whats the question? You want to execute your catch block in both saveGame() and performAction()?

Comment: No, I just literally don't know how to call on the method saveGame(...) in a way that works...

Comment: @NoamHudson the error which is being generated is handled at 2 levels. That's it. What problem are you facing while calling `saveGame()` method?

Comment: If I just try to call the saveGame() method without using using any kind of 'try {} catch {}' thing, I get the following error in compilation:
"unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      saveGame(fileName); }"

Comment: can you paste saveGame() code?

Comment: than you´re missing the correct way to catch the exception, but it would be way more easy to help you if you´d include the `saveGame` code within your question aswell.

Comment: saveGame() code added

Comment: Because your method throws the IOException: `saveGame(String mazeGameSave) throws IOException` you don't need to have a try/catch within that method but you do when the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `throws IOException` clausule from saveGame().

You're already catching an IOException in your `catch (IOException e){}` block.

**Throws** clausule means that method can throw an exception during execution, so when you're calling that method in another, you need to surround the call by try catch block.